# Right to retract on tenancy agreement renewal (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, rent, tenancy-rules, dog

My tenancy agreement is ending soon, I currently want to have a dog and asked our current landlord if it is possible, I explicitly stated that I would not renew the tenancy if I could not have a dog. We discussed about what kind of dog and he finally agreed. I asked him to also discuss with the building management to see if dogs are allowed in the premise. He replied that he asked and that everything is ok.

Happy about that, I sent to the real estate agency the confirmation that I want to stay for one more year.

Today I received a message from the landlord stating: "The building management will consult a solicitor to establish if the landlord's permission is enough."

How legal is that? Do I have a right to retract in this case? Should I have done things differentely ? (I am not UK national)

Answer (score 2):

### If you can’t have a dog, you don’t have a lease

Your offer was conditional on your being allowed a dog and it was accepted on that basis. If something (landlord, owner’s corporation, council etc.) prevents you having a dog then your condition has not been satisfied and you have no contract.

Comment: Do you have any citations supporting that in UK law?